# Python: How to label this dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
                   'Category':['A','A','IOU','A','B','B','IOU','IOU','IOU','C','IOU']})
```

[image]

I'd like to label `CaseNo` col based on this condition:
For each `CaseNo`, if there is an occurrence of value 'IOU' in `Category` column with any values (except 'IOU') **preceding** it - label 'YES', else label 'NO'.

How can I do this in Python? Expected outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC and assuming that `YES` should only be set when there's at least one `IOU` *and some value other than `IOU` preceding it*:

```
m = (df.Category.eq('IOU').view('i1')
       .groupby(df.CaseNo)
       .transform(lambda x: x.diff().eq(1).any()))
df['Label'] = m.map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
```

---

```
print(df)

    CaseNo Category Label
0        1        A   Yes
1        1        A   Yes
2        1      IOU   Yes
3        1        A   Yes
4        2        B    No
5        2        B    No
6        3      IOU    No
7        3      IOU    No
8        3      IOU    No
9        4        C   Yes
10       4      IOU   Yes
```

---

The idea here is that `Series.diff()` will be 1, when there is a 1 (`IOU`) preceded by a `0` (no `IOU`)

Comment: hmm can explain `.view('i1')`?

Comment: That just views the boolean result of `df.Category.eq('IOU')` as integers @spiderman . Then the idea is that you take the difference of the groups, which will now contain `0`s and `1`s . And if there is a `0,1` subsequence within them, the group will be `YES`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `transform` with `first` and `any`

```
g=df.Category.eq('IOU').groupby(df['CaseNo'])
m=g.transform('any') & ~g.transform('first')
df['New']=m.map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
df
Out[24]: 
    CaseNo Category  New
0        1        A  Yes
1        1        A  Yes
2        1      IOU  Yes
3        1        A  Yes
4        2        B   No
5        2        B   No
6        3      IOU   No
7        3      IOU   No
8        3      IOU   No
9        4        C  Yes
10       4      IOU  Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you need. It uses `groupby` and `index`. The advantage is you can always modify the function `func` to make an update in what you want. The other answers are no doubt specific but can't be modified much.

```py
def func(x):
    try:
        return 'YES' if x.index('IOU')!=0 else 'NO'
    except:
        return "NO"
mapper = df.groupby("CaseNo")['Category'].agg(list).apply(func)
df['Label'] = df['CaseNo'].apply(lambda x: mapper[x])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    CaseNo Category Label
0        1        A   YES
1        1        A   YES
2        1      IOU   YES
3        1        A   YES
4        2        B    NO
5        2        B    NO
6        3      IOU    NO
7        3      IOU    NO
8        3      IOU    NO
9        4        C   YES
10       4      IOU   YES
```

Answer (score 1):

`Groupby` with a count of `IOU` is one way to solve it :

```
res = (df
       .assign(val = df.groupby('CaseNo').Category.transform(",".join),
               label = lambda x: np.where(x.val.str.count("IOU").eq(1) ,"YES","NO")
              )
       .drop('val',axis=1)
      )

res


    CaseNo  Category    label
0      1       A        YES
1      1       A        YES
2      1      IOU       YES
3      1       A        YES
4      2       B        NO
5      2       B        NO
6      3     IOU        NO
7      3     IOU        NO
8      3     IOU        NO
9      4       C        YES
10     4     IOU        YES
```